# How to fix ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0 in Python

Tags: python

I'm using a piece of code that is supposed to be able to detect road damage from images by some trained models. This is part of the code that checks statistical information of the dataset to calculate the number of total images and labels. There is an error with the xml.etree

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.dom import minidom
import collections
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as matplot
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline



cls_names = []
total_images = 0
for gov in govs:

    file_list = os.listdir(base_path + gov + '/Annotations/')

    for file in file_list:

        total_images = total_images + 1
        if file =='.DS_Store':
            pass
        else:
            infile_xml = open(base_path + gov + '/Annotations/' +file)
            tree = ElementTree.parse(infile_xml)
            root = tree.getroot()
            for obj in root.iter('object'):
                cls_name = obj.find('name').text
                cls_names.append(cls_name)
print("total")
print("# of images：" + str(total_images))
print("# of labels：" + str(len(cls_names)))
```

I expect the number of images and number of labels to show

Comment: Remove the `%matplotlib inline` because it's only valid when running the script in a notebook.

Answer (score 0):

The exception indicates that one of the files you're trying to load isn't well formed XML. Try surrounding the `ElementTree.parse()` section in a `try...except` block, and printing the filename so you can see which file has the problem.

**Update**:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree, ParseError
from xml.dom import minidom
import collections
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as matplot
import seaborn as sns

cls_names = []
total_images = 0
for gov in govs:

    file_list = os.listdir(base_path + gov + '/Annotations/')

    for file in file_list:

        total_images = total_images + 1
        if file =='.DS_Store':
            pass
        else:
            try:
                infile_xml = open(base_path + gov + '/Annotations/' +file)
                tree = ElementTree.parse(infile_xml)
                root = tree.getroot()
                for obj in root.iter('object'):
                    cls_name = obj.find('name').text
                    cls_names.append(cls_name)
            except ParseError:
                 print("Parse error with %s", file) 
print("total")
print("# of images：" + str(total_images))
print("# of labels：" + str(len(cls_names)))
```

Comment: I'm a noob so please show me how i would write that